# How much XP do Rare monsters and Champions give?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am currently farming with an archon build, and am averaging 8 to 10 million xp an hour.

Sometimes, though, I get killed by a rare monster or champion.  Should I bother finishing the job, or should I just kill mionion after minion?

I suppose those rare monsters must give more XP, but I don't know how much.  Does anyone have a comparison between regular monster XP, and rare/champion monster XP?

Comment: I don't know about their XP, but they definitely drop more loot and seem to have a higher chance of dropping uncommon and rare items.

Comment: I get far better item by buying low and selling high in auction house.

Answer (score 1):

Relative to their base experience Blue Champion demons will give 3x the amount of experience of their normal counterparts, White demons in Yellow Champion packs will grant normal experience, Yellow Champion demons will grant 5x the amount of experience as normal. Any illusions summoned by these champions offer no extra experience.

The linked infographic gives a good outline of how much exp is given for each monster kill throughout all acts on inferno.

http://i1007.photobucket.com/albums/af193/Loignite/ExperienceGraph-1.png

Whilst it may be tempting to skim around these monsters, it is always advisable to turn down the MP if you're having problems, remember there's a higher chance to drop on items from all champion monsters.